# Is it possible to access a bean variable in jsf?

Tags: jsf

I want to access a string variable from a managed bean and compare it another value and thereby render a table only if they are equal.

Can anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 4):

put the table in a ui:panel and then in the rendered attribute of the panel put some EL, like

```
rendered="#{mybean.myProperty eq 'mystring'}"
```

Comment: Thank U!, but i want to use scriplets. How can i access the bean variable in a scriptlet?

Comment: no scriptlets in jsf (with facelets).  You can write a custom EL function to perform further logic if you need to.